# Warning/Error using xmlReadFile in C

Tags: c, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, libxml2

```
<element1 type="type1" name="value1">
  <start play="no"/>
  <element2 aaa="AAA"/>
  <element2 bbb="BBB"/>
  <element3 ccc="CCC">
     <element4/><!-- play="no"/>-->
  </element3>
</element1>
```

And I use following code to parse it:

```
int parse( const char *xml) {

    printf("Entered\n");
    xmlDoc  *doc = NULL;
    doc = xmlReadFile(xml, NULL, 0);

    if (doc == NULL)
        printf("Could not parse file\n");
    else {
        printf("Success\n");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    }

    xmlCleanupParser();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get following error:

```
Entered
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<element1 type="type1" name="value1">
  <start play="no"/>
  <element2 aaa="AAA"/>
  <element2 bbb="BBB"/>
  <element3 ccc="CCC">
     <element4/><!-- play="no"/>-->
  </element3>
</element1>

"
Could not parse file
```

Comment: this one `<!-- play="no"/>-->` looks scary.

Comment: What is `xml` in `doc = xmlReadFile(xml, NULL, 0);`?  Is it the name of a file of the actual XML text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the first argument to

```
xmlReadFile(xml, NULL, 0);
```

is the *name* of the file, not the XML string itself. The error message indicates that you passed the actual XML to the method.  I believe there is an `xmlReadMemory()` method that will suit your needs.

Comment: I think you are right. I have an intermediate function that converts the file to XML stream. What should I use to read the XML stream?

Comment: Use `xmlReadMemory()`, as you could have easily found on the [libXml2 website](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html) under Code Examples.